# Any good jQuery caching plugin?

Tags: caching, jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

When I log-in to my Gmail Inbox it starts caching the mails one-by-one in JavaScript.
When I click on a mail in the Inbox, it doesn't send an Ajax request then to fetch the mail contents.
Instead it serves from an already cached JavaScript array.

Is there any good jQuery plugin to implement this?

I came across a few but they don't seem to be under active development.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCache
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCacher

Any better plugin?

Edit1:
My requirement is exactly same as what Gmail is doing.
There is a ticket management system which shows a list of open tickets(say 100 tickets on a page) and once you click on a ticket its details are displayed. I want to cache the details of all 100 tickets displayed on the page.

I am planning to implement the cache as object of key-value pairs only. But I am looking for a plugin which takes care of tasks like setting/getting values from cache, auto-updating the cache periodically etc.

Storing in JS object shall be enogh for me. I don't see any advantages of using HTML5 local storage as
* No offline browsing is required and
* I wan't to load fresh data every time a new window is opened
* I won't need huge amount of memory

Comment: Seems to me that cache characteristics are going to be heavily dependent on your application's features and typical uses.

Comment: Per Pointy. A simple cache shouldn't be very difficult -- it may well be as simple as an object of key-value pairs.

Comment: Edited the question to answer your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pointy suggested, the cache implementation was indeed heavily dependent on my application. Hence I have written my own code to handle this requirement. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some of the new html5 localstorage http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html

Comment: Do you see any benefit of storing in html5 storage over storing in JavaScript object? Anyways I am looking for the plugin which takes care of setting/getting/auto-updating the cache. So whatever storage I use, a plugin for handling it would be great.

Comment: @Varun: 1. HTML5 localStorage data is shared between all tabs/windows with the same domain. 2. HTML5 localStorage data persists when all tabs and windows are closed and will be accessible next time the domain is used in a new tab/window.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google is rather using HTML5 local storage than caching. They seem to be big fans of HTML5 and adopt anything as soon as it's available. If you must use cookies, I'd recommend [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) one.

Comment: If you want to store stuff locally without storing it permanently, you just assign it to a global variable. However, once you click on links, the object has to be reloaded again. So I was thinking you might need a more permanent storage and those are only available through either cookies or html5 local storage (the way google is doing it).